# Inner div becomes larger than outer and overshoots browser border, padding-right not working

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have 2 divs the parent div is 100% width and the inner 75rem,
so if you increase the browser width the text will stay in the center.
Like here: [www.profimetall.de](http://www.profimetall.de) or [www.pip-laser.de](http://www.pip-laser.de) (navbar).

Now I want to reduce the browser width and give both divs a 100% width but the inner should have a gap between the outer on. The left side is not the problem,
rather the right side. When I decrease the browser width the div gets to wide and the scrollbar at the bottom pops up.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {width: 100%; height: auto, position: relative;}
.inner {width: 75rem; height:300px; position: relative; margin: 0 auto;}
```

CSS: (max-width: 80rem)

```
.inner {width: 100%; padding-right: 40px; padding-left: 40px;
```

After the media querie it should like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6S8Z.png

gray: outer div
yellow: inner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some typos:

`height: auto,` should be: `height: auto;`

and obviously the last .inner is missing `}`.

But to the problem at hand, try adding `box-sizing:border-box;` to `.inner`. That should account for the padding.